# Kafka Leader not found for Topic and Partition

Tags: apache-kafka, clj-kafka

I have been facing an issue, some of the partitions for multiple topics on the Kafka cluster have no leader and even no replica in the isr(in-sync replica) set.

This has happened for all the partitions of a particular broker id - 5.

```
topic: topic1   partition: 2        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:   
topic: topic1   partition: 8        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic1   partition: 14   leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic2   partition: 1        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic2   partition: 8        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic2   partition: 15   leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic3   partition: 1        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic3   partition: 8        leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:  
topic: topic3   partition: 15   leader: -1  replicas: 5 isr:
```

I have tried the replication tools to manually assign broker to these partitions but that did not helped. As none of them are in isr set.

Unfortunately the replication factor for these topics was 1. But for topics where the replication factor was higher, the problem persists. There the leader has been assigned to the next preferred replica but the replica on corrupt broker is not moved to isr set even after long time(days) and partitions have logs in order of 100s.

```
topic: topic4   partition: 1    leader: 6   replicas: 5,6   isr: 6
```

For same topic, the partition where leader was not broker 5(corrupted broker) there broker 5 is still in isr set.

```
topic: topic4   partition: 0    leader: 4   replicas: 4,5   isr: 4,5
```

Another observation, the corrupted broker has topic creation log in its INFO logs, printed very frequently, every minute

```
[2014-12-09 13:07:27,878] INFO Topic creation { "partitions":{ "0":[ 4, 3 ], "1":[ 5, 4 ] }, "version":1 } (kafka.admin.AdminUtils$)
```

Though there are no new topics getting created on the cluster.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? How can I fix it?

Kafka version 0.8.1

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue.. Did you by chance found the root cause and the solution?

Comment: Have you found out any solution of this problem?